# Why does str() changes output after data-cleansing

Tags: r, data-structures

When getting to know the data i've placed in a df, i use str and dim.
Here str produces kind of two "sections" of output, which is much the same, as you can see down below.

After i've done some cleansing and run str() again it suddenly stops returning the second "section".
I'm learning to work in R, and it has me puzzled.

Please, if you have some sort of explanation, i will be grateful.

All the best, Anders

```
> str(spain)
Classes ‘spec_tbl_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    76 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ SNo            : num  552 619 688 758 828 ...
 $ ObservationDate: chr  "02/01/2020" "02/02/2020" "02/03/2020" "02/04/2020" ...
 $ Province/State : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Country/Region : chr  "Spain" "Spain" "Spain" "Spain" ...
 $ Last Update    : chr  "2/1/2020 2:13" "2020-02-01T23:43:02" "2020-02-01T23:43:02" "2020-02-01T23:43:02" ...
 $ Confirmed      : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ Deaths         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Recovered      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "spec")=
  .. cols(
  ..   SNo = col_double(),
  ..   ObservationDate = col_character(),
  ..   `Province/State` = col_character(),
  ..   `Country/Region` = col_character(),
  ..   `Last Update` = col_character(),
  ..   Confirmed = col_double(),
  ..   Deaths = col_double(),
  ..   Recovered = col_double()
  .. )
> dim(spain)
[1] 76  8
> spain <-  spain[,-3] #Fjerner kolonne 3
> str(spain)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   76 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ SNo            : num  552 619 688 758 828 ...
 $ ObservationDate: chr  "02/01/2020" "02/02/2020" "02/03/2020" "02/04/2020" ...
 $ Country/Region : chr  "Spain" "Spain" "Spain" "Spain" ...
 $ Last Update    : chr  "2/1/2020 2:13" "2020-02-01T23:43:02" "2020-02-01T23:43:02" "2020-02-01T23:43:02" ...
 $ Confirmed      : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ Deaths         : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Recovered      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you are reading in you data, but this is the expected outcome after you subset a data frame with a subclass `spec_tbl_df`.

The short-ish answer is that your data has a subclass `‘spec_tbl_df’` when it is first imported into R. This subclass has a `spec` attribute that holds the columns' data type information. When you call `str()`, it shows the class types (`‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame'` ...) and any attributes (`attr(*, "spec")`). By design, after you subset a `spec_tbl_df` this attribute is dropped. In practice, this doesn't impact your data frame. I would think of this as an artifact of loading in your data.

You can read a little bit more about it here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/news/news.html